# Reliable Stateful Service vs. Event Hub

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, signalr, azure-service-fabric, azure-eventhub

With Microsofts new microservice framework is it possible to build stateful services. Is it possible to use such a service to receive data from different devices instead of using Event Hubs? E.g. my devices push data to a stateless web api service (maybe with SignalR in near real time) and the api service forward the data to a realiable stateful service in a reliable queue. Or to a reliable actor.

These services are scalable, so why should I use Event Hub for this purpose? Is there any performance or latency problem sending the data directly to the service without Event Hub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes in theory and in practice you can build your own stateless service which is highly scalable and accepts as much load as you want. In most scenarios it will be acceptable.

In terms of money it will cost you considerably more to host instances of services which only receive data and forward to Actors, comparing to Event Hub subscription. You have to pay for every Service Fabric instance and actually write business logic to deal with scalability, even though SF makes it trivial there is still space for failures and bugs.

Event Hubs are designed to be stressed on incredibly massive scale most projects won't ever reach. They are optimised for low latency and easily deal with millions of requests per second. If this is not your case don't bother.

You only need to run an Event Hub event listener in your fabric because it acts as a reliable "front door" to the stream of messages, and makes the server architecture somewhat simpler and more reliable. It's an architectural decision mostly, depends on the project.

Comment: Thanks! The stateless backend api service is already there as my entrypoint to the application. Ok, I'm trying to use the api service for few devices. But I get your point, when I have a lot more devices it is probably wiser to use a message system. I was wondering about the performance compared to an own service as device entry point. I'm trying to avoid to use too much cloud services because of eventually moving to a private cloud if it is wanted from the customer.